# Converting a String Array into an Int Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, converters

I am trying to create a sorting system and I am attempting to turn a fairly long list of integers in string form into an int array to more easily be able to sort the array. The initial string array is formed via reading a list of integers from a text file.

This is how the code currently looks and I am currently working on the basis of sorting the year:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;



namespace Climate_Sorting_Application
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string[] monthArray = File.ReadAllLines("Month.txt");
        public static string[] yearArrayPre = File.ReadAllLines("Year.txt");
        public static string[] afArray = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_AF.txt");
        public static string[] rainArray = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_Rain.txt");
        public static string[] sunArray = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_Sun.txt");
        public static string[] tmaxArray = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_TMax.txt");
        public static string[] tminArray = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_TMin.txt");
        public static string[] af2Array = File.ReadAllLines("WS2_Rain.txt");
        public static string[] rain2Array = File.ReadAllLines("WS2_Rain.txt");
        public static string[] sun2Array = File.ReadAllLines("WS2_Sun.txt");
        public static string[] tmax2Array = File.ReadAllLines("WS2_TMax.txt");
        public static string[] tmin2Array = File.ReadAllLines("WS2_TMin.txt");
        public static string arrayToAnalyse;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Specify the Data to be Analysed");
            Console.WriteLine("You must specify the Text File name (Do not include .txt");
            arrayToAnalyse = Console.ReadLine();



            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void sortProcess()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way of easily converting to the correct data type? Or even a way of converting it to an int value array during the initial file reading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure! LINQ can really make things simple:

```
int[] someArray = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

That will run every line that's read in through the `int.Parse()` method and then convert those results to an array.

Answer (score 0):

ToCharArray?   A Char is simply an int in memory.

Or you could read the string in A for loop and do an int.parse(index).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c7h58e5(v=vs.110).aspx